# Directly access value based on another value in anonymous array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, hashtable, associative-array

Given the following anonymous array of hashes:

```
$AoH = [
    {    
         'FORM_FIELD_ID'        => '10353',
         'VISIBLE_BY'           => '10354',
         'FIELD_LABEL'          => 'ISINCIDENT',
         'VALUE'                => '',
         'DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL'  => 'Yes No',
         'FORM_ID'              => '2113',
    },
    {
         'FORM_FIELD_ID'        => '10354',
         'VISIBLE_BY'           => '0',
         'FIELD_LABEL'          => 'CATEGORY',
         'VALUE'                => 'zOS Logical Security (RACF)',
         'DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL'  => 'CATEGORY',
         'FORM_ID'              => '2113',
    },
    {
         'FORM_FIELD_ID'        => '10368',
         'VISIBLE_BY'           => '10354',
         'FIELD_LABEL'          => 'STARTDATE',
         'VALUE'                => '',
         'DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL'  => 'REQTYPE',
         'FORM_ID'              => '2113',

    }
];
```

How would I directly access the `FIELD_LABEL` value given that I knew the `FORM_FIELD_ID` is 10353?

I know I can loop through `@$AoH` and conditionally find `$_->{FIELD_LABEL}` based on `$_->{FORM_FIELD_ID} == 10353`, but is there anyway to directly access the wanted value if one of the other values in the same hash is known?

Comment: If you want direct lookup, you need to remap your FORM_FIELD_ID to a hash key instead.

Comment: Oh my!  Satori like insight ... in the [`Devel::REPL`](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::REPL), using `dd @$AoH` then remapping with `my %by_form_field_id = map { $_->{FORM_FIELD_ID} => $_ } @$AoH;` then `dd %by_form_field_id` visually demonstrates where the speed would come from. +1 TLP and amon.

Comment: A good basic and helpful question. TLP's comment and @amon's answer make it useful for learning about making simple things faster. (Changed tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not unless you change your data structure. You could e.g. index the records by their form field id:

```
my %by_form_field_id = map { $_->{FORM_FIELD_ID} => $_ } @$AoH;
```

Then:

```
my $field_label = $by_form_field_id{10353}{FIELD_LABEL};
```

Without changing the data structure, you really have to `grep`:

```
my $field_label = (grep { $_->{FORM_FIELD_ID} == 10353 } @$AoH)[0]->{FIELD_LABEL};
```

Comment: if your `@AoH` is more than trivial in size indexing the array from a hash element like this would be best. +1 for amon who makes it look easy. @amon  ... you are making a %HoH's so the "->" is optional and `by_form_field_id{10353}{FIELD_LABEL}` looks really clean and simple. Is it more perlish to use this data structure approach or would writing a custom search function to use `grep` count as acceptable in TIMTOWTDI sense?

Comment: @G.Cito Creating the lookup hash is an *O(n)* operation, as is `grep`ping. If I have to perform multiple lookups, I'd create the hash, as each lookup runs in *O(1)*. I.e. for *m* lookups (*m > 1*), using a hash is *m* times as fast as `grep`. For a single lookup, `grep` is faster. I don't care about Tim Toady, as long as the right tool for the job is used.

Comment: amon, Thanks for that response.  I still think I'm operating on the script and small tools side of the perl universe since the grep "shellism" (admittedly a perl function of course) is what first occurred to me. I haven't quite reached the stage where I naturally grok modifying  data structures to be computationally efficient. I enjoy posts that help me on this path. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a function loop through `@array` and examine the `%hash` or maybe use the builtin `grep` method:

```
say $_->{FIELD_LABEL} for (grep { $_->{FORM_FIELD_ID} == 10353 } @$AoH )
```

works.  And so does this:

```
say %$_->{FIELD_LABEL} for (grep { $_->{FORM_FIELD_ID} == 10353 } @$AoH )
```

but it gives a `Using a hash as a reference is deprecated` warning (with `pumpkin perl-5.16.3`).